# Pip install - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 4096: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Struggling with pip install. When running this command from Command line, I am getting this

> C:\Users\username>pip install
> ERROR: Exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
> status = run_func(*args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
> return func(self, options, args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py", line 326, in run
> session = self.get_default_session(options)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 98, in get_default_session
> self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
> session = PipSession(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\session.py", line 343, in **init**
> self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\session.py", line 175, in user_agent
> setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
> return next(matches, None)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 183, in 
> matches = (
> ^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
> for dist in self._iter_distributions():
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 175, in *iter_distributions
> yield from finder.find(location)
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 79, in find
> for dist, info_location in self.*find_impl(location):
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 64, in *find_impl
> raw_name = get_dist_name(dist)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_compat.py", line 52, in get_dist_name
> name = cast(Any, dist).name
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\metadata_*init**.py", line 622, in name
> return self.metadata['Name']
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\metadata_*init**.py", line 610, in metadata
> self.read_text('METADATA')
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\metadata_*init**.py", line 938, in read_text
> return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1059, in read_text
> return f.read()
> ^^^^^^^^
> File "", line 322, in decode
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 4096: invalid start byte
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
> File "", line 88, in *run_code
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\main.py", line 70, in main
> return command.main(cmd_args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 101, in main
> return self._main(args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 216, in _main
> self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 179, in handle_pip_version_check
> session = self._build_session(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
> session = PipSession(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\session.py", line 343, in **init**
> self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\network\session.py", line 175, in user_agent
> setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
> return next(matches, None)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 183, in 
> matches = (
> ^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
> for dist in self._iter_distributions():
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 175, in *iter_distributions
> yield from finder.find(location)
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 79, in find
> for dist, info_location in self.*find_impl(location):
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_envs.py", line 64, in *find_impl
> raw_name = get_dist_name(dist)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_internal\metadata\importlib_compat.py", line 52, in get_dist_name
> name = cast(Any, dist).name
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\metadata_*init**.py", line 622, in name
> return self.metadata['Name']
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\metadata_*init**.py", line 610, in metadata
> self.read_text('METADATA')
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\metadata_*init**.py", line 938, in read_text
> return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1059, in read_text
> return f.read()
> ^^^^^^^^
> File "", line 322, in decode
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 4096: invalid start byte

Tried repair with installer; reinstall Python - all didn't help. How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the **exact command** triggering the error?

Comment: @CristiFati pip install ...

Comment: @CristiFati seems you've asked what's exact command. "pip install pandas", for example, or any other package